# Content Below Post Code Not Working

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am using this code to add some buttons with shortcode in functions.php## Heading ## then it is working :

```
function add_after_post_content($content) {

    if(!is_feed() && !is_home() && is_singular() && is_main_query()) {

        $content .= '<p><b>Setup/Medicine Download<b></p>[maxbutton id="1"]';
                $content .= '[maxbutton id="2"]';
                $content .= '[maxbutton id="3"]';
    }
    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'add_after_post_content');
```

But when I add some Html code after that then it does not work :

```
function add_after_post_content($content) {
    if(!is_feed() && !is_home() && is_singular() && is_main_query()) {

      $content .=  '<table style="border: solid 1px #ffffff;width:100%;">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <h3><b><span style="color: #555; ">About Author</span>&nbsp;</b>
        <input type="hidden" name="stats" value="2498">
        </h3>you can be an author too, join mhktricks and show you skills</td>
        <td style="border: solid 1px #ffffff;" align="right">
        <a href="http://mhktricks.net/user-registration/" target="_blank">
        <input class="p2graybtn" style="height: 26px; width:150px;" type="button" value="Join Us">
        </a>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <hr>
        <table style="border: solid 1px #ffffff;">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>

        <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ), 70 ); ?>
        </td>
        <td style="border: solid 1px #ffffff;">
        <table style="border: solid 1px #ffffff;">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <span style="color: #555;font-size:20px;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;font-style: normal;text-decoration: none;">
        <?php echo get_the_author(); ?>
        </span>
        <br><div style="margin-left:1px;">
        <?php echo get_author_role(); ?>

        <span style="position:relative;top:1px;margin-left:5px;"><img src="http://i2.wp.com/codex.onhax.net/img/verified.png" height="12" width="12"></span>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td style="border: solid 1px #ffffff;">
        <div style="margin-left: 3px;margin-top: -17px;border: #B8B8B8 1px solid;border-radius:2px;padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;font-size:10px;">
        <?php the_author_posts(); ?> POSTS</div>';
        </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table><div style="margin-top:-12px;">&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left:3px;margin-top:2px;padding-right:60px;">
        <?php the_author_meta( 'description' ); ?> 
        <a class="author-link" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ); ?>" rel="author">
           View all posts by me 
        <?php get_the_author(); ?>
        <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>
        </a>        
        </div>
        </td>   
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <hr color="white">
        <hr color="white">
        <table style="border: solid 1px #ffffff;width:100%;">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <h3><b><span style="color: #555; ">Discussion</span></b></h3>
          share your knowledge.mind to help others</td>
        <td style="border: solid 1px #ffffff;" align="right">
        <a href="#" class="show-comments">
        <input class="p2graybtn" style="height: 26px;" type="button" value="Toggle Comments">
        </a>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>';
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_after_post_content');
```

When I add the above code the page even doesn't load.
I just want to add author box below posts but it does not work. Help Please !

Answer (score 1):

If you'd bothered to look, you have a `'` in your html, which is terminating your string assignment:

```
[...long snip...] the_author_posts(); ?> POSTS</div>';
                                                    ^---
    </td>
```

which turns that `</td>` into PHP code, causing a fatal parse error.

This is why massive multi-line strings like this are a horrible idea. If you need to dump text like that, use a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc), or drop out of PHP mode. e.g.

```
$content = <<<EOL
blah blah blah all your html here blah blah blah
EOL;
```

HEREDOCs removes the need to worry about quotes.

You should also turn on `display_errors` and `error_reporting`, which would have told you about the fatal error. They should NEVER be off on a devel/debug system.

Comment: It makes the page to load but the author box does not appear ...
I think the EOL removes the Html operations ...